# crawling url \ how to get dynamic links in node.js

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I'm using js-crawler to crawl websites, and encountered now with CNN, that part of [its landing page links are inside](http://view-source:http://edition.cnn.com/)  (urls that are generated dynamically, for some reason).
Thing is crawler don't really touch scripts - how should I address it? should I write my own code in addition to my node.js crawler? is there advanced crawler that knows how to handle this dynamic behavior?

Comment: Crawling content that is generated by client-side Javascript is a complicated problem that not even Google has fully solved.  The only way to truly do it is to use some sort of head-less browser on your server where the page is loaded into a browser-like environment where it can run its own scripts and generate its own content and then you can examine the resulting DOM.  Even then, it won't necessarily generate content that requires user interaction (like clicking on a tab to show some content).

Comment: make it reponse so I could vote for it! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer:

Crawling content that is generated by client-side Javascript is a complicated problem that not even Google has fully solved.

The only way to truly do it is to use some sort of head-less browser that is safely sandboxed on your server where the page is loaded into a browser-like environment where it can run its own scripts and generate its own content and then you can examine the resulting DOM.

Even then, it won't necessarily generate content that requires user interaction (like clicking on a tab to show some content).